# Cant return to appropriate JSP from Spring Controller with @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a simple spring controller like below:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/public/{someid}/home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goHome(Model model, @PathVariable String someid, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        logger.debug(someid);

        return "home";
    }
....
}
```

Now what I want is to render the home.jsp from folder /public/home.jsp in my webapp. However, when I hit /public/abc/home.htmlHowever it returns a 404 error , I think its looking for /public/abc/home.jsp which obviously does not exist.

I have the following spring mapping for viewresolvers

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value></value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please advise any changes I need to do in controller or the view resolver configuration.

Here is my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-webapp.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cm</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cm</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cm</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>entityManagerFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>entityManagerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please note that all my other URLs/controller work fine ... Only this one is causing issues as it has a dynamic element to it. Cant figure out the viewresolver for this one.

Comment: Does your application execute line logger.debug(someid)?

Comment: @mvb13 Yes. it does. Also it works fine when I dont have the @RequestMapping(value = "/public/home.html"... in request mapping

Comment: @Sandhu - thanks, but that didnt work. logger gets executed, but does not render my page :(

Comment: @Dilpa could you post your web.xml?

Comment: where is your home.jsp? is it directly in your `webapp`?

Comment: its under webapp/public/home.jsp

Comment: Do you have SimpleUrlHandlerMapping bean in your configuration?

Comment: No , I have InternalResourceViewResolver

Answer (score 1):

You didn't configure your ViewResolver. You should specify path to your jsps.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>"/WEB-INF/views/"</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I do have a view resolver. Please see my original question. Please note that my configuration works fine if I dont have the @PathVariable  in the controller.

Comment: Check the value of property prefix in ViewResolver in my post and compare with your variant.

Comment: Why should I add the prefix as WEB-INF when my jsps are outside ? Also my configuration works fine for other jsps that I have !

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think this will help you

@Controller

public class SimpleController{

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/public/{someid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String goHome(Model model, @PathVariable String someid) throws Exception {
    logger.debug(someid);

    return "home";
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The method goHome is not even called. I cant see the logger output. Sorry, its not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A method may be able to resolve this problem:

You don't need add the PathVariable as a folder and just attach it as a parameter.
You could change the handle value `/public/{someid}/home.html` into `/public/home.html{someid}` or `/public/home{someid}`

Handle value just a value,you don't have to write it as strict folder structure.